# Create chart/statistics for selected mysql table through python

Tags: python, mysql, excel-2007, mysql-python

I'd like to start by asking for your opinion on how I should tackle this task, instead of simply how to structure my code.

Here is what I'm trying to do: I have a lot of data loaded into a mysql table for a large number of unique names + dates (i.e., where the date is a separate field). My goal is to be able to select a particular name (using rawinput, and perhaps in the future add a drop-down menu) and see a monthly trend, with a moving average, and perhaps other stats, for one of the fields (revenue, revenue per month, clicks, etc). What is your advice - to move this data to an excel workbook via python, or is there a way to display this information in python (with charts that compare to excel, of course)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Analyze of such data (name,date) could be seen as issuing ad-hoc SQL queries to get timeseries information.

You will 'sample' your information by a date/time frame (day/week/month/year or more detailled by hour/minute) depending of how large is your dataset.

I often use such query where the date field is truncate to the sample rate, in mysql DATE_FORMAT function is cool for that (postgres and oracle use date_trunc and trunc respectivly)

What you want to see in your data is in your your WHERE conditions.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%Y-%m-%d') as day,
       COUNT(*) as nb_event
FROM yourtable
WHERE name = 'specific_value_to_analyze'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

execute this query and output to a csv file. You could use direct mysql commands for that, but I recommend to make a python script that execute such query, and you can use getopt options for output formatting (with or without columns headers, use different separator than default one, etc). And even you can build dynamically the query based on some options.

To plot such information, look at time series tools. If you have missing data (date that won't appears in result of such sql query) you should take care for the choice. Excel is not the correct one for that, I think (or not master enough it), but could be a start.

Personaly I found dygraph, a javascript library, really cool for time series plotting, and it can be used with a csv file as source. Careful in such configuration, due to crossdomain security constraint, the csv file and html page that display the Dygraph object should be on the same server (or whatever the security constraint of your browser want to accept).

I used to build such webapp using django, as it's my favourite web framework, where I wrap url call as this :

```
GET /timeserie/view/<category>/<value_to_plot>
GET /timeserie/csv/<category>/<value_to_plot>
```

The first url call a view that simply output a template file with a variable that reference the url to get the csv file for the Dygraph object :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  g3 = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graphdiv3"),
    "{{ csv_url }}",
    {
      rollPeriod: 15,
      showRoller: true
    }
  );
</script>
```

The second url call a view that generate the sql query and output the result as text/csv to be rendered by Dygraph.

It's "home made" could stand simple or be extended, run easily on any desktop computer, could be extended to output json format for use by others javascript libraries/framework.

Else there is tool in opensource, related to such reporting (but timeseries capabilities are often not enough for my need) like Pentaho, JasperReport, SOFA. You make the query as datasource inside a report in such tool and build a graph that output timeserie.

I found that today web technique with correct javascript library/framework is really start to be correct to challenge that old fashion of reporting by such classical BI tools and it make things interactive :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be broken down into two main pieces: analyzing the data, and presenting it. I assume that you already know how to do the data analysis part, and you're wondering how to present it.

This seems like a problem that's particularly well suited to a web app. Is there a reason why you would want to avoid that?

If you're very new to web programming and programming in general, then something like [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/) could be an easy way to get started. There's a [simple tutorial here](http://giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=811).

For a desktop database-heavy app, have a look at [dabo](http://dabodev.com/). It makes things like creating views on database tables really simple. [wxpython](http://www.wxpython.org/), on which it's built, also has lots of simple graphing features.

Comment: I would not be opposed to a web app, I'm just pretty new at programming altogether...I wanted to take baby steps towards creating a web app, but if you think it would be the way to go, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I edited my response to recommend web2py, because it makes it very simple to get started with web programming, and all your development is done right in the browser.